# How to add lite & pro version of library via CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, static-libraries

I have my own static library which has two versions - lite & pro. 
It's in private repo.
I've added separate private Podspec for each version. 
Libs are as compiled static .a files with header files (not open source).

Adding to project like this:

```
# common cocoapods stuff here

abstract_target 'CommonPods' do

  # some other pods here 

  target 'App' do
    pod 'BaseSDK'
  end

  target 'AppPro' do  
    pod 'ProSDK'
  end
end
```

But somehow both targets in project are linked with latest version used in Podfile - 'ProSDK' and if switch lib versions for targets or set Base lib for Pro target - both targets will be linked with 'BaseSDK'.
Is there any lib with lite / pro versions in cocoapods? Or any thoughts about it, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project has 2 targets and own .xcconfig files and there are #include CocoaPods .xcconfig files in it. But mistate was to #include both CocoaPods .xcconfig files for Base & Pro Podfile targets like so:

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-CommonPods-App/Pods-CommonPods-App.debug.xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-CommonPods-AppPro/Pods-CommonPods-AppPro.debug.xcconfig"
```

And 'Other LD flags' has been overwrote by latest. 
So I've added new .xcconfig files in order to separate .xcconfig files for targets one of which includes Pods-CommonPods-App/Pods-CommonPods-App.debug.xcconfig and other Pods-CommonPods-App/Pods-CommonPods-AppPro.debug.xcconfig (same for release of course).